# How to override registry path for fireDAC or DBExpress vendorLib

Tags: delphi, firedac, dbexpress

RadStudio Berlin (Delphi)

I have a situation where my laptop has odbc drivers installed and pointing to a VM IP on the laptop.

When I connect to customer data, I'm constantly having to change the vendorlib path to point to their network path located odbc driver dlls.

For DBExpress, I've tried:

```
scn1.DriverName:='odbc';
scn1.VendorLib:='\\server\folder\dbodbc11.dll';
```

and set params like:

```
ConnectionString=DRIVER={SQL Anywhere 11};DBN=PSI;ENG=PSI;ASTOP=NO;INT=NO;...
```

Overriding the vendorlib as above does not use the drivers from the path I set, but instead uses the drivers from the path associated with DRIVER={SQL Anywhere 11} as set in my laptop registry.

If I'm at a customer site, the vm where those drivers exist isn't running, so the connection fails.

If there are NO drivers associated with the DRIVER param on my laptop, the vendorlib with full path works quite nicely.

I can't seem to work out how to tell DBExpress to ignore the driver paths as defined in the registry.

FireDAC FDConnection does the same (looks for driver path in registry), except I'm not sure how to begin overriding the VendorLib path.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: DBX relies on two Ini files, DBXConnections and DBXDrivers, and when you get problems, it is often because the OS isn't using the pair you are expecting.  Have you tried providing custom DBXConnections & DBXDrivers .Ini files?  You may find multiple instances of these on your target machine.  The OS will use the pair it finds first on the PATH, iirc.

Comment: You're trying to say that even if you specify a fully qualified path to a driver in the [VendorLib](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FireDAC.Phys.TFDPhysDriverLink.VendorLib) property of the [TFDPhysASADriverLink](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FireDAC.Phys.ASA.TFDPhysASADriverLink) component, the engine searches for driver in registry rather than using the one you specified? That should not happen.

Comment: To check which driver is in use, you can evaluate (and if I'm not mistaken receive a fully qualified path of the used driver) `ShowMessage(TODBCConnection(FDConnection1.CliObj).Lib.DLLName);` I guess.

Comment: @MartynA - I never distribute the DBXnnn.ini files - everything is configured at run-time in the applications - so there won't be any copies, let alone potential multiple copies, to be found.

Comment: @edbored:  Sure, I just didn't know whether you were aware of these two files.

Comment: @MartynA - thanks - I've been gleefully avoiding distributing them since I first started using DBExpress in D7...

Comment: @Victoria - "That should not happen." - that does NOT happen. I'd been setting everything directly in TFDConnection. As soon as I started using FDPhysODBCDriverLink instead, it all works the way I'd expect it to. Thanks for that - now I need to work out how to do this in DBExpress!

Comment: Good news :) You said how to do it in DBX or FireDAC, hence I commented just FireDAC because I would definitely prefer FD. I'm not keen in DBX but the reference has a few notes about what you tried. `DriverName` loads a "stored profile" (if you set `DriverName`, the engine _"automatically sets the LibraryName and VendorLib properties"_). So all that might be necessary is setting `VendorLib` and since it is deprecated and should be specified in `Params`, all you need here could be `Conn.Params.Add('VendorLib=<path to driver>');` without `DriverName` nor `LibraryName` keys specified.

Comment: @Victoria - "Data source name not found and no default driver specified"

Comment: @Victoria  I've tried variations on this, but it looks like it really, really wants an ODBC DSN configured, or a "DRIVER=" param to search registry for the vendorlib. I'm thinking I might need to register a "fake" driver class at runtime to get this to point to the correct DLL. More work than just creating a utility to change registry on my laptop! Thanks again - I'm slowing moving to FD, this will push me on.

Comment: Then setting `DriverName` can load from those "settings" more than `VendorLib` and `LibraryName`. I can't investigate this more as I'm on tablet now, sorry.

Comment: @edbored managed to find a way to load the dll from another way, am I practically experiencing the same problem with the dbExpress SQLConnection?